# How to generate SOAP message XML from WSDL and its imported XSDs

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, cxf

I'm currently using Apache CXF to dynamically create a client (JaxWsDynamicClientFactory) and then generating java classes corresponding to the Operation selected, which i'm using to send the request and receive its response.
Additionally, i need to generate the XML of a SOAP request message with Java, so as to dynamically create a UI with Swing for the user to input the values for each element.

How can i go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask try google, for instance http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Comment: I think you misunderstood what i need. I already have the webservice created and running, and i can use it with my Java app. What i do need, is to dynamically create the XML (or extract the message elements) from the operation WSDL specification in order to create a GUI for the user to input the values for each message element.